# How to dynamically call a html page

Tags: angularjs

I currently `ng-include` an html doc.

```
<div ng-include="'templates/calendar.html'"></div>
```

behind the scenes, this document loops through a javascript object to create the calendar. However, I plan to have updates to that object and I'd like to set up a click event to re-load `calendar.html` using the updated object. **How can I do this?**

Comment: Question doesn't make sense in angular context. When you update the data model the view will be updated. Without showing any code it is impossible to answer this

Comment: The data should not be embedded into the template. The template should be static. And you should simply make an $http call to reload the data, as JSON, put that data in the scope, and have the template redisplay the new data automatically thanks to data-binding.

Comment: you wouldn't *normally* reload the template, but if you need to reload the template, then this would be a job for a directive, not a job for `ng-include`.

Comment: that being said, the way you are describing how you want to accomplish the task you presented sounds like you have a fundamental misunderstanding of angular overall.

Comment: Yeah, it's my second day with angular

Comment: providing the code that shows your attempts is the only way we can see what you are trying and where you are actually going wrong.

Comment: I think I'll have to continue running through tutorials. I want something like a function that loads the html page like `<button ng-onclick="'templates/calendar.html'"></button>`. I just don't know how to ask good questions yet

Comment: that doesn't really even make sense.  why would you want the user to click a button to change a template?

Comment: not to change a template, but to reload it. in the template I use `ng-repeat`, so once the object is updated the output from the template will be different

Comment: `ng-repeat` is dynamic, it doesn't need you to tell it to reload.  Why don't we start with trying to figure out what it is you are actually trying to accomplish, rather than the solutions you don't think will work?  the more you try to describe what you think your challenges are, the more this is coming out as an [XY Problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can create a directive and give it the calendar template to show.

Your directive will get some data (which you want to display) in a scope. Use your scope data to populate the template. Then, when your data changes, replace the data in the scope and the view will change itself accordingly.

You won't need to reload the template.

Update:

Try this code in jsfiddle to see the demonstration of the concept:

```
<div ng-app="Demo" ng-controller="ChildCtrl">
    <iso-element></iso-element>
</div>
```

Js part:

```
angular.module("Demo", [])  
  .controller("ChildCtrl", function($rootScope, $scope, $interval) {
    var flipWording = function () {
      if ($scope.data === 'Hello Galaxy') {
        $scope.data = 'Hello World';
      } else {
        $scope.data = 'Hello Galaxy';
      }
    };
    $scope.data = "Hello World";
    $interval(function () {
      flipWording();
    }, 2000);
 })
.directive("isoElement", function() {
  return {
    restrict: "E",
    template: '<p>{{data}}</p>', // You can give a path here as well like abc/foo.html
    scope: true,
    link: function(scope) {

    }
  };
});
```

Because the scope data gets flipped the directive shows updated value every time.